# Finding derivatives occurring in an expression

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis

I would like to find the derivatives of a function `U[x,y,t]` occurring in an expression `X`. I use

```
DeleteDuplicates[Cases[X, Derivative[__][U][__], Infinity]].
```

An output would be something like this:

```
{Derivative[1, 0, 0][U][x, y, t], 
 Derivative[0, 1, 0][U][x, y, t], 
 Derivative[0, 2, 0][U][x, y, t], 
 Derivative[1, 1, 0][U][x, y, t], 
 Derivative[2, 0, 0][U][x, y, t], 
 Derivative[0, 1, 1][U][x, y, t], 
 Derivative[1, 0, 1][U][x, y, t], 
 Derivative[0, 0, 1][U][x, y, t],
 Derivative[1, 1, 1][U][x, y, t], 
 Derivative[0, 2, 1][U][x, y, t]}
```

However, if I want to find a particular nth derivative of `U`, say 3rd derivative, in the expression to get the following:

```
 {Derivative[1, 1, 1][U][x, y, t], 
 Derivative[0, 2, 1][U][x, y, t]}
```

how would I achieve that?

Comment: do you have a specific  example of an input?

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: I meant an example of the PDE itself, you want to find those patterns in, so to be clear. i.e. the PDE which to apply the pattern on. I can then show how to do it on the PDE. This way there is no confusion. It is what you call the expression `X`

Comment: X can be any PDE, even a system of PDEs, not necessarily linear. Using the above function will result something like the output provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specialise your pattern:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Cases[X, Derivative[i__][U][__]/;Plus[i]==3, -1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

> X can be any PDE, even a system of PDEs, not necessarily linear.

```
getPatterns[expr_, pat_] := 
  Last@Reap[expr /. a : pat :> Sow[a], _, Sequence @@ #2 &];

pde = Derivative[1, 1, 1][U][x, y, t] + 
   Derivative[0, 2, 1][U][x, y, t]^3 + 
   Derivative[0, 1, 1][U][x, y, t] + Sin[x] + F'[x] + 
   Derivative[3, 0, 0][U][x, y, t] + Derivative[2, 1, 0][U][x, y, t];

getPatterns[pde, 
 Derivative[x0_, y0_, t0_][U][_, _, _] /; x0 + y0 + t0 == 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Function `getPatterns` is thanks to Carl Woll.